# Modificación operador copia para uso restringido

Tags: c++, template

Estoy realizando un programa que sobrecarga operadores con templates. Ahora mismo el programa funciona para los tipos de la clase Forma. No obstante, ahora querría restringir dicho operador para que solamente funcione con un  tipo  específico de Forma.

```
template < int DIM1, int DIM2>
class Forma
{
double value;
public:

int a;
int b;

public:

Forma(double in) : value(in) {
    a = DIM1, b = DIM2;
}
//Getters
const double get_data() const { return value; }

//Setters
const void set_data(double d)  {value=d; }

  template<int DIM3, int DIM4>
  Forma( Forma<DIM3,DIM4> const& otro)
    : Forma(otro.get_data())
  { }

 template<int DIM3, int DIM4>
 Forma const& operator=(Forma<DIM3,DIM4> const& otro)
  {
    set_data(otro.get_data());
    return *this;
 }
};
```

Si quisiese que el operador de asignación (copia) sobrecargado compilase solamente para la asignación `Triangulo = Circulo` pero no por ejemplo para `Circulo = Cuadrado` **¿Cómo habría que modificar dicho operador?**

Comment: Te puedes llegar a complicar mucho la vida con eso... ¿es realmente necesario? Sinceramente creo que hay mejores formas de abordar el problema

Comment: La idea es que las operaciones sobrecargadas solo sirvan para unos tipos de datos, con esto se quiere restringir diferentes operaciones como Circulo x= a*b siendo a de tipo circulo y b de tipo triangulo, pero por ejemplo permitir Triangulo y= c *d siendo c un circulo y d un cuadrado. ¿A qué otras formas te refieres?

Comment: Lo que no termino de ver en ese caso es basar la lógica en plantillas

Comment: Bueno, es que en este caso he reducido los tipos que puede haber pero serían unos 15 o así. Sin embargo la restricción sería para un tipo solamente.

Comment: Da igual si son 15 o 500 tipos... las plantillas son para definir comportamientos genéricos y esto dista mucho de ser un comportamiento genérico... por eso lo digo

Comment: Todos tendrían el mismo comportamiento salvo uno, a eso me refería. De todas formas, no me han dado margen de maniobra en la elección de si usar templates o no.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78098/discussion-between-eferion-and-adamista).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si he entendido correctamente lo que has comentado, lo que necesitas no es tanto un operador de conversión sino implementar correctamente los operadores.

En el caso del operador `*` entenderé que las dimensiones se multiplican.

Así, si tenemos:

```
using Cuadrado  = Forma<1,1>;
using Triangulo = Forma<1,2>;
using Circulo   = Forma<1,4>;
```

Podríamos hacer las siguientes operaciones:

```
Cuadrado = Cuadrado * Cuadrado
Triangulo = Cuadrado * Triangulo
Circulo = Cuadrado * Circulo
Circulo = Triangulo * Triangulo
```

Pues bien, esto se consigue, como te he comentado, implementando correctamente el operador de multiplicación:

```
template<int DIM1, int DIM2, int DIM3, int DIM4>
Forma<DIM1*DIM3,DIM2*DIM4> operator*(Forma<DIM1,DIM2> const& a, Forma<DIM3,DIM4> const& b)
{
  return {a.get_data()*b.get_data()};
}
```

Dicho esto, tu plantilla es un tanto confusa ya que tiene elementos innecesarios:

```
template < int DIM1, int DIM2>
class Forma
{
  double value;

public:

  int a; // <<--- 1
  int b; // <<--- 2

public:

  Forma(double in) : value(in) {
      a = DIM1, b = DIM2; // <<--- 3
  }

  //Getters
  const double get_data() const { return value; }
//^^^^^
// 4

  //Setters
  const void set_data(double d)  {value=d; }
//^^^^^
//  5
};
```

Donde:

1. Esa variable es innecesaria, para eso tienes `DIM1`
2. Variable innecesaria, para eso tiemes `DIM2`
3. En virtud de los puntos 1 y 2, estas asignaciones sobram
4. La función devuelve una **copia** de `value`, no ganas absolutamente nada haciendo constante la copia.
5. con `void` no se puede hacer nada (no se puede almacenar ni asignar a ninguna variable), luego aquí también sobra `const`

El código con la limpieza hecha debería parecerse más bien a este:

```
template < int DIM1, int DIM2>
class Forma
{
  double value;

public:

  Forma(double in)
    : value(in)
  { }

  //Getters
  double get_data() const
  { return value; }

  //Setters
  void set_data(double d)
  { value=d; }
};

template<int DIM1, int DIM2, int DIM3, int DIM4>
Forma<DIM1*DIM3,DIM2*DIM4> operator*(Forma<DIM1,DIM2> const& a, Forma<DIM3,DIM4> const& b)
{
  return {a.get_data()*b.get_data()};
}

using Cuadrado  = Forma<1,1>; 
using Triangulo = Forma<1,2>;
using Circulo   = Forma<1,4>;

int main()
{
  Triangulo a{1.5}, b{2};
  Circulo c = a * b;
  std::cout << c.get_data();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Añadiendo la multiplicación de DIMS en Forma<...> ha funcionado perfectamente.